# spring boot Maven project import error in sts

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I am facing error while importing spring boot maven project in sts-4.6.0.RELEASE :

An internal error occurred during: "Importing Maven projects".
org/springframework/tooling/boot/ls/xml/XMLRootElementContentDescriber2$QualifiedElement

Java version installed in my laptop is 1.8.0_241 and maven version is 3.6.3 below is the image attached of the error which i am facing while importing spring boot project..

[image]

Below is pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
       <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
   <groupId>com.developer.app.ws</groupId>
   <artifactId>mobile-app-ws</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>mobile-app-ws</name>
   <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

   <properties>
       <java.version>1.8</java.version>
   </properties>

   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
           <scope>test</scope>
           <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                   <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Please  add `pom.xml` file also and check maven plugin is compatible or not.

Comment: this looks like a bug to be in the XML support in Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse. Please file an issue at https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/ and attach the screenshot. Please also take a look at the Error Log View and add the details from there to the report, since the exact stack trace of the error would be quite useful.

Comment: Thanks Martin sure i will do that. When i have downgraded the sts to 3.9.12 then its working. Also i have observed that when i am trying to open any xml file in sts4.6.0 version whether its pom.xml or test.xml which i created later this issue is coming up.