# An internal error occurred during "updating maven project" in STS(4.8.0)

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, sts

I have cloned a repo from bitbucket to my local machine and when it tries to build i am getting the above error. Rather i am getting errors on every maven related stuff (build , update ,clean) and I am not sure what's wrong . I am not even able to open pom.xml file in STS.
Detailed error ->
An internal error occurred during "updating maven project"
org/springframework/tooling/boot/ls/xml/xmlrootelementcontentdescriber2$qualifiedelement

Comment: Looks like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60911620/spring-boot-maven-project-import-error-in-sts. Martin Lippert, the developer of STS, says _"Please file an issue at github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues and attach the screenshot. Please also take a look at the Error Log View and add the details from there to the report, since the exact stack trace of the error would be quite useful."_

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: i switched to STS version 4.7.0 and the maven issue got resolved. Not sure what's wrong with version 4.8.0

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by this way:-

1. close your IDE.
2. start your IDE through by Run as Administrator.
3. update your project->maven update